# How to design application with rollback capability

Tags: design

I am currently working on an application (basically its a kind of execution engine capable of running user defined jobs and generate output in real time) that needs to handle rollback functionality, it might sound crazy but is it possible to have such thing at the application level? e.g. imagine some user tries run a job J1 and once it is started to execute he wanted to Edit/Modify it , 
 - that means the current running job has to be killed, 

- all the action taken so far must be reverted and 

- re-run the job J1 again

few things that comes in my mind is we must anyhow store or maintain application states somehow, somewhere and then call the rollback stuff along with the previous save points. I was reading few articles on DB level rollback but the scenario does not fit in this case as 
it need to work on a real time environment.

But I am unable to find a proper approach as to how to proceed and what else should be taken into considerations. 
Please let me know if this sounds unclear, I shall try to provide more info if possible.

Any help or advice?

Comment: I suggest reading up on the [memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Comment: Most Databases offer rollback with transaction mechanisms. If you could store all state in a DB you could use that.

Comment: what factors should be taken into consideration while defining what to save and when to save?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you need rollback in terms of transactions (a job either completes or not, there are no partial job results) or do you need undo functionality?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I need undo functionality .. the application supposed to work on real time scenario ... so I guess rollback in terms of a transaction (update once the whole process is done) is not a proper fit

Comment: What is a "real time environment"?

Comment: suppose you are working with a queue (reading messages or input) and doing some computation on top of it and producing output.

Comment: then you must using mamento pattern, the idea is to save each state of your queue so you able to rollback to whenever state you want, use @Oded suggestion

Comment: You can also have a look at Rockford Lhotka's [CSLA framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/).  It has Undo capability built-in.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to ask a new question.  Just a post a new question that references this one.  Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Real time system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) or not, the [memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) is an excellent place to start.

> The memento pattern is a software design pattern that provides the ability to restore an object to its previous state (undo via rollback).
>   The memento pattern is implemented with three objects: the originator, a caretaker and a memento.
>   The originator is some object that has an internal state.
>   The caretaker is going to do something to the originator, but wants to be able to undo the change. The caretaker first asks the originator for a memento object. Then it does whatever operation (or sequence of operations) it was going to do.
>   To roll back to the state before the operations, it returns the memento object to the originator.
>   The memento object itself is an opaque object (one which the caretaker cannot, or should not, change).
>   When using this pattern, care should be taken if the originator may change other objects or resources - the memento pattern operates on a single object.

I broke up the Wikipedia article a bit in order to draw focus on some items.

For your scenario, the originator is going to be your primary application code, most likely at the point where jobs are registered and start processing.

The caretaker is what you need to create and could be some kind of logging system or other data store.

The memento is going to be the relevant information that needs to be undone and / or redone.  I suspect this will look like a job description of some sort that can be placed back onto the processing queue.

If you can wrap the existing changes from the job `J1` with a database transaction, that will take care of your rollback concerns (`all the action taken so far must be reverted`).  When a transaction rollback occurs, you would trigger a call to the Caretaker in order to re-queue job `J1`.

One thing to keep in mind is that last warning in the Wikipedia summary.  You need to make sure that the changes are atomic and that they can be applied or rolled back as a cohesive set.

I'm not sure that being in a real time environment will have much impact upon how you implement the memento pattern.  If there are deadlines for activities, then you may need to profile some of the changes in order to make sure the system responds in an appropriate amount of time.  I think I would implement the functionality first and then verify you are meeting your other application requirements.  I don't foresee you running into anything that would invalidate what you have described so far.

Answer (score -2):

https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-rollback-well
https://continuousdelivery.com/implementing/patterns/

1. Architecturally support Rollback – CI/CD
   a.  Blue/Green deployments,
   b.  Canary releases or Launch Darkly - releasing features to a subset of your users
   c.  Feature flags/Feature toggles – releasing code and releasing a feature are not tied together, enable or disable feature during runtime.
   d.  Microservices / independently deployable components
   e.  Smaller components and Agile release to keep what we rollback to minimum
   f.  Rolling updates  - Smaller but frequent releases are better than a big bang approach
   g.  Publish, point of no return
2. Adoption of tools
   a.  Liquibase
   b.  OCP/Containerization
   c.  Terraform /Cloud
   d.  LaunchDarkly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).